# What are the differences between Lubuntu and LXDE sessions?

Tags: lubuntu, lxde

Lubuntu login manager lets you choose between a Lubuntu session and a LXDE session. Apart from the wallpaper ( :p ) what are the differences between them? I've also noticed that the average CPU temperature on my laptop is lower when I'm on a LXDE session.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the different theme, and icons, I couldn't find any other differences. Even the number of processes was exactly the same. You can see all running processes with `ps aux`, and `ps aux | wc -l` to get their number.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know what are the differences, but I know that on my brand new asus eee-pc:

- with the "Lubuntu" session, it was almost impossible to connect to any networks (ethernet, wireless, or mobile broadband) and none was spontaneously looked for; whereas,
- with the "LXDE" session, all available networks (ethernet, wireless, and mobile broadband) were spontaneously looked for and connected to.

Why? No idea. But I spent last night on it. So that difference is a pretty big one for me!

PS: just found interesting:

- the first comment of this anwer: https://askubuntu.com/a/80504/36119
- the second post of this thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1853350