# Installed Ubuntu In a low Specs PC and it is too slow, even with LXDE

Tags: 11.10, boot, freeze, performance, lxde

I'm new with Linux and started with Ubuntu 11.10, I installed it in my PC (Core2Duo 2Ghz, 512Mb Ram DDR2, integrated video in Motherboard), I know the requirements for Unity are 1Gb Ram so I decided to download a Desktop environment more lightweight, so I Installed LXDE, it loads very fast, compared to the 3.5 min from login screen to open desktop in Unity, but it freezes every time I open a single program, I can't even navigate in Internet, it freezes, sometimes for a pair of minutes and the graph at bottom right is all green as if iyt were using 100% CPU, it happens with every program.

As additional data it takes 3+ min to get from boot system selection screen to Login screen and 3.5 Min more to get into Ubuntu with Unity, with LXDE it turns to 30 secs aproximately.

Is Ubuntu + LXDE Desktop Environment Package = Lubuntu? or should I download Lubuntu directly instead?

I installed some other desktop environments, as Gnome but it doesn't log in, the screen just turns grey.

Should I get an older Ubuntu version?

I'm thinking about uninstalling Ubuntu but I'll try to deplete the options, thanks for your support.

Comment: is the integrated video adapter using its own memory or using some of the system RAM?. With so little RAM that would slow things down a great deal. You have a choice: get more system RAM or a discrete video card with at least 1GB of memory. Better still do both.

Comment: Well that's more than en enough to run Lubuntu blazingly fast, maybe it's using too much swap (virtual memory) instead of the RAM, ia have it running on a netbook, and that was casuing it to be so slow.

Comment: Lubuntu as in `lubuntu-desktop` uses more RAM than just `lxde` why? i'm not sure but it does.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by Ubuntu + LXDE Desktop Environment Package?
Is it Ubuntu mini + lxde package (as `sudo apt-get install lxde`) or which way did you get this?

Lubuntu is (I guess) Ubuntu mini + `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`, not exactly just clean lxde package.
Lubuntu should work pretty fast on your computer, if not - it's most likely hardware problems.

I created mine current system (Ubuntu mini + lxde) on virtualbox where i gave it 1 prcessor and 512 MB RAM and it's lightning-fast and extremely responsive.

If you're new to Ubuntu or linux I would suggest getting Lubuntu, because mini+lxde leaves you with fully functional system but at some points it's hard to configure.

P.S. if you Gnome/KDE programs, even under LXDE, they will be slow anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Lubuntu also comes with lighter applications than the ones from Ubuntu, that affects your experience too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ubuntu + lxde=lubuntu and i really recommend that you download lubuntu for a cleaner ubuntu install I have a dell d600 laptop running lubuntu pentium m and 768 ram 30 gigs in Hard drive and I'm very happy with it.

Download from [HERE](http://lubuntu.net/)

Comment: Not exactly, LXDE+Ubuntu= Ubuntu being able to use LXDE and Openbox, and just the LXDE session at login, the Lubuntu Session is different, it even uses more RAM.